# SpringBoot unit test does not use @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation from Application class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to configure a Spring Boot Application so that no DB is used at all.
So I have annotated my Application class for excluding JPA autoconfig classes:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

This works fine when the service is run standalone

Unfortunately my test classe seems to ignore the annotation, although I use the Application class for my test

```
@Slf4j
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class SwaggerJsonExistenceTest {
    ...
}
```

The test fails with the following error message

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot
>   determine embedded database for tests. If you want an embedded
>   database please put a supported one on the classpath.

Update: 
There are no DB drivers on the classpath.

org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa is used for testing (included via testCompile directive in gradle)

How has the test to be configured so that it does not use db-related autoconfiguration?

Fix: I have removed all jpa starter dependencies (as no DB is needed), so that datasource autoconfig is not done at all.

Comment: do you have any database driver on classpath? Which spring boot starters do you use? if you do, remove it. It will stop any db-autoconfiguration magic.

Comment: @BartoszBilicki I have removed all jpa starter dependencies. it works now, thx. although I still don't know, why excluding the classes does not work for the test...

Answer (score 0):

The `@SpringBootApplication` annotation has an exclude property, which you should use in favor of `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = ...)` in this case. If you use it, the `@SpringBootTest` annotated tests should enforce the exclude correctly.

[Spring Boot API - SpringBootApplication](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html)

Comment: I have removed the EnableAutoConfiguration annotation and now use the exclude property of @SpringBootApplication. Unfortunately the test still fails with the same error message

Comment: That is odd. Please try excluding `JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class` as well.

Comment: If you don't need any database, you don't need Spring Data, which you included via spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Comment: yep, did that as a result of Bartosz' comment

Answer (score -1):

I'm had this issue with version 2.0.9.RELEASE, which I have to use to stay in compliance with my company standards.  What worked for me was:

```
@SpringBootTest(properties="spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration")
```

I can't say for certain if this is an issue with @EnableAutoConfiguration in my version of Springboot, but with version 2.1.5.RELEASE, I do not have to set the property with the @SpringBootTest to make this work.